# Responsive nav bar, but some content outside the hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

Here's code.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="toggle-button">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <div class="test">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hide" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hide" href="#">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hide" href="#">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link hide" href="#">Forum</a>
      </li>
      </div>
      <li class="nav-item nav-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    width: 93%;
    padding-left: 3.5%;
}

.nav-item {
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: inline;
}

.nav-right {
    float: right;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: 200ms;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: goldenrod;
}

.navbar .toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
    top: 18px;
    left: 18px;
}

.navbar .toggle-button span {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 666px) {
    .nav-item .hide {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar with the hamburger manu. Basically I want contents in div.test in the hamburger menu and login and sign up outside it. But after creating it, I found out that the sign up and login is not on the same line as div.test. I don't have how to fix it since I've wrote margin: 0; and there is still margin that is filling up the whole line. I have no idea what to do now so please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `.nav-right`;
2. Add the `Login` and `Sing up` buttons into `div` container like so:

```
      <div>
        <li class="nav-item nav-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-right">
        <a class="nav-link" href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
      </li>
      </div>
```

3. Use `flex-box` on the `.navbar-nav` to arrange the items, side by side, and use `justify-content: space-between to push them to the edges of the parent.` align-items: center` will center the item vertically.

```
.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    width: 93%;
    padding-left: 3.5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/poOadzX?editors=1100

Here you can read more about css flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Oh I found something wrong, when I hide the div "test", the login will flow right again, how can I make it still flow right?

Comment: You gonna need to use `position: absolute` for that. I have updated the codepen

Comment: Solved, sorry for the slow reply, I was unable to get on this website. Thank you so much!